# I got "DisconnectedContext occured" C#

Tags: c#, winforms, disconnect

Hi guys

I'm new in Windows Form C#, I have a lot of windows forms in my project, when I click on Login button  of  "Log_Menu" windows form to go to "Plano_Aula" windows form,  I got "DisconnectedContext occured"

I'm also using a library in my project to make audio recognition, I have no idea what the problem is.

My english is not very good , but if you don't understand leave a comment here, and I try to explain it.

Follow the code

**1 - Click on the button Login**

```
    private void Btn_Entrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string login = txbLogin.Text;
        string senha = txbSenha.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(senha))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não pode haver campo(s) vazio(s)");
            return;
        }


        if (login.Contains("'"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não é permitido usar caracteres no login");
            return;
        }
        if (senha.Contains("'"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não é permitido usar caracteres '  na senha");
            return;


        }



         professor = new Professor();


        if ((professor.Codigo = professor.autenticarProfessor(login, senha))                   != null)
        {
            professor.bindProfessor(login, professor);    

            this.Close(); //Fecho esta tela
            this.Dispose(); //Dispose nela
            th = new Thread(abrirTela_Plano_Aula); //Abro uma nova linha de 
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
        }
        else {

            MessageBox.Show("Dados incorretos");
            return;
        }
    }
```

**2-This method opens "Plano_Aula" Form**

```
    private void abrirTela_Plano_Aula()
    {
        Application.Run(new Plano_Aula(professor)); //Aqui chamo a nova tela

    }
```

**3 - Construtor "Plano_Aula"**

*Here I get the picture of professor and I check on about  the professor who's logged*

```
    public Plano_Aula(Professor professor)
    {
        this.professor = professor;
        InitializeComponent();
        //Foto professor logado
        imgProfessor.ImageLocation = professor.FotoProfessor;
        imgProfessor.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(professor.FotoProfessor))
        {
            if (professor.Sexo == "M")
            {
                professor.FotoProfessor = new ConfigurarImagemSistema().getImg("fotoAlunoDesconhecido", "M", "chamada");
                imgProfessor.ImageLocation = professor.FotoProfessor;

            }
            else if (professor.Sexo == "F")
            {
                professor.FotoProfessor = new     ConfigurarImagemSistema().getImg("fotoAlunaDesconhecido", "F", "chamada");
                imgProfessor.ImageLocation = professor.FotoProfessor;

            }

        }
```

Here's the picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kpDL.jpg

Comment: As far as I can tell are you killing the main-window/thread and then making a new thread. While all this, you are accessing a global variable in the mainthread context... Something is definitely wrong here even if I'm not an expert and can't really give a clear answer. But I would start with using `ParameterizedThreadStart` instead of a global variable and closing the mainwindow after creating the new thread.

Comment: I think I solved the problem, I was running my project in x64, I changed it to x86  until now I'm not having this exception, but I can't tell if it was the problem.

Comment: Well if it works then it's fine but I still recommend to clean up your code a bit. Nice code will always help you and as this seems to become a bigger project it's even more useful to have reliable and good code. And I personally find it very strange that x64->x86 leads to such an error.